# Why does football still use the offside rule?

Tags: rules, football, fifa

There used to be other sports like [field hockey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offside_(field_hockey)) where they used to have an offside rule. To continue with the example of field hockey, the games were too defensive, and they weren't that many goals (which makes a sport less attractive to watch).

To prevent this, they abolished the offside rule (which was similar to the one in association football if I'm not mistaken). The results of this abolishment was that the sport became more offensive, there were much more goals and at the end it became more popular because of this.

Why doesn't FIFA abolish this rule? Games where there are a lot of goals are the best ones to watch and would make the sport more popular in the US for instance. Even more, the offside rule is often the most contested one and the most difficult to spot correctly.

Comment: Also related: [What's the relevance of the offside rule?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/15256/whats-the-relevance-of-the-offside-rule).